# Web Config, Insert a virtual directory under appSettings Tag

Tags: iis, web-config

I have a web application in my IIS server with a Virtual directory "_login". I need to call this virtual directory properly from appSettings using the correct method.

I have tried

`<appSettings>
  <add key="Sample" value="~/_login/ProductImages/" />
 </appSettings>`

However, this is not correct. How do I get the exact folder (Virtual Directory)?

Comment: Here providing ~/ is not working to access the Virtual Directory.